# tensorflow_lite Prelu unsupport dims->size = 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

In `tensorflow_lite` demo `tflite_simple_example`,I use my `Rnet.tflite` ,I get error as follow

```
if (interpreter->AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk) {
NSLog(@"Failed to allocate tensors.");
exit(-1);
}
```

> error:tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/activations.cc:171
>   input->dims->size != 4 (2 != 4)
>
> In activations.cc I find PreluPrepare() TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context,
>   input->dims->size, 4); my input->dims->size =2
>
> ```
> TfLiteStatus PreluPrepare(TfLiteContext* context, TfLiteNode* node) {
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, NumInputs(node), 2);
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, NumOutputs(node), 1);
> const TfLiteTensor* input = GetInput(context, node, 0);
> TfLiteTensor* output = GetOutput(context, node, 0);
> const TfLiteTensor* alpha = GetInput(context, node, 1);
>
> output->type = input->type;
>
> // Currently only Float32 is supported
> // TODO(ycling): Support other data types.
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, input->type, kTfLiteFloat32);
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, alpha->type, kTfLiteFloat32);
>
> // Currently, only support 4D input and 3D alpha with shape
> // (1, 1, channels).
> // TODO(impjdi): Support other cases where alpha is broadcastable
> // to input.
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, input->dims->size, 4);
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, alpha->dims->size, 3);
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, alpha->dims->data[0], 1);
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, alpha->dims->data[1], 1);
> TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, alpha->dims->data[2], input->dims->data[3]);
>
> return context->ResizeTensor(context, output,
> TfLiteIntArrayCopy(input->dims));
> }
> ```

Source code / logs

```
input = Input(shape=[24, 24, 3],batch_shape=[1,24, 24, 3])
x = Conv2D(28, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='valid', name='conv1')(input)
x = PReLU(shared_axes=[1, 2], name='prelu1')(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=3,strides=2, padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='valid', name='conv2')(x)
x = PReLU(shared_axes=[1, 2], name='prelu2')(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=3, strides=2)(x)

x = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), strides=1, padding='valid', name='conv3')(x)
x = PReLU(shared_axes=[1, 2], name='prelu3')(x)
x = Permute((3, 2, 1))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, name='conv4')(x)
x = PReLU( name='prelu4')(x)
classifier = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='conv5-1')(x)
bbox_regress = Dense(4, name='conv5-2')(x)
model = Model([input], [classifier, bbox_regress])
model.load_weights(weight_path, by_name=True)

x = PReLU( name='prelu4')(x) input x->dims->size =2
```

How can I slove this problem?